# "The D-PHY specification defines the maximum lane flight time to 2 ns." Why?

Tags: transmission-line, camera, interconnect

I'm hoping someone can explain to me why the maximum lane flight time matters.

Impedance matching, skew, attenuation, etc. all make sense to me as a natural limitation to how long an interconnect can be, but I do not see why the absolute time the signal travels would be a limitation.

Comment: Interest: [AD AN1337](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-1337.pdf)  MIPI CSI-2 is designed as a chip to chip interface; therefore, it
does not transmit over long distances. The D-PHY specification
defines the maximum lane flight time to 2 ns. Using standard
printed circuit board (PCB) materials and design rules (for
example, transmitting MIPI CSI-2 through a microstripline on
a standard FR4 PCB), results in a maximum trace length of 25 cm
to 30 cm. ...

Comment: ...Therefore, keep the MIPI CSI-2 traces from the
ADV7280-M, ADV7281-M, ADV7281-MA, or ADV7282-M
transmitter device to the MIPI CSI-2 receiver under 30 cm in
length. -> Mainly they are saying it doesn't **need** to be long so we've defined it this way  :-). At full speed that's a number of bit times. || Also https://wiki2.org/en/Camera_Serial_Interface || https://www.mipi.org/specifications/csi-3 ||

Comment: A basic CSI-3 v1.1 link configuration using four forward lanes and one reverse lane (10 total wires) can support up to 14.88 Gbps (usable bit rate, including 8B10B and UniPro overhead) in the fwd direction and typically supports 1 Mbps or more in the reverse direction. The UniPro stack itself uses some link bandwidth (primarily in the reverse direction) for the purpose of guaranteeing reliable packet delivery to the receiver. Cameras implementing a minimal MIPI CSI-3 configuration consisting of one forward and one reverse lane (four total wires) can transmit 12 BPP 4K video at about 40 FPS.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're referring to MIPI.

The 2ns figure comes up in a number of places (e.g., in MIPI D-PHY spec v1.1, Annex B1.) From the doc:

---

B.1 Practical Distances
The maximum Lane flight time is defined at two nanoseconds. Assuming less than 100ps wiring delay within the RX-TX modules each, the physical distance that can be bridged with external interconnect is around 54cm/√ε. For most practical PCB and flex materials this corresponds to maximum distances around 25-30 cm.

---

What they are saying is that they wish to limit the practical cable length to 20-30cm and a capacitive load of 70pF. One reason is the influence on LP-mode: greater load capacitance will affect rise/fall times for this slow mode.

At any rate, 20-30cm of cabling is consistent with MIPI D-PHY's mission as an internal interconnect using PCB or flex cable.

There is also some time dependencies when making transitions between LP and HS mode (as well as bus turnaround for DSI), where too much added time-of-flight could cause glitches in the hand-off between the two modes.